# Why does submitting an upload form not send data?

Tags: php, sql, forms, upload

I'm trying to submit a form, that should upload a picture and also put it's name in the database, for some reason it does not submit anything nor upload anything, it goes on like nothing. The site reloads every time I submit.

**Form:**

```
    <form name="myForm" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

        <div class="id-input">ID:</div>
            <label class="input2 red bold">
                <?php if(isset($beg_u_id)) echo($beg_u_id);?>
            </label>

        <input class="input" name="mon_by" value="<?php if(isset($beg_u_titel)) echo($beg_u_titel);?>" placeholder="By">

         <input class="input" name="mon_title" value="<?php if(isset($mon_u_by)) echo($mon_u_by);?>" placeholder="Title">

        <div class="button-area">
            <input class="btn-upload" type="file" name="mon_img">
            <div class="btn-upload-true">Vælg fil</div>
            <div id="file_name">img/months/<?php if(isset($mon_u_img)) echo($mon_u_img);?></div>
        </div>

        <input class="btn" name="mon_submit" type="submit" value="<?php if ($mode == 'update') echo 'Opdater'; elseif ($mode == 'insert') echo 'Opret'; ?>">
        <a href="panel.php?page=monthspicture.php">
            <button class="danger-btn" type="button" href="">Annuller</button>
        </a>

    <input type="hidden" name="mon_id" value="<?php if(isset($beg_u_id)) echo($beg_u_id);?>">
    </form>
</div>
```

**Submit code:**

```
<?php

$id = $_POST["mon_id"];

$mon_i_img = "";

if($_FILES['mon_img']['error'] == 0){
    $target_dir = "../img/months/";
    $target_file_only = basename($_FILES["mon_img"]["name"]);
    $target_file = $target_dir . $target_file_only;
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["mon_img"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "<div class='success-box'>File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".</div>";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "<div class='error-box'>File is not an image..</div>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "<div class='error-box'>Sorry, file already exists.</div>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["mon_img"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "<div class='error-box'>Sorry, your file is too large.</div>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg") {
        echo "<div class='error-box'>Sorry, only JPG, JPEG & PNG files are allowed.</div>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "<div class='error-box'>Sorry, your file was not uploaded.</div>";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mon_img"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {    
            echo "<div class='success-box'>The file ". $target_file_only . " has been uploaded.</div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div class='error-box'>Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.</div>";
        }

    }

    if ($uploadOk == 1) {
        $mon_i_img = $target_file_only;
    }

}

$mon_i_title = $_POST["mon_title"];
$mon_i_by = $_POST["mon_by"];

if (empty($mon_i_title) || empty($mon_i_by)) {
    header ("Location: panel.php?page=monthspicture.php&create=empty");
    exit;
}

$mon_i_id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($mob_i_id);
$mon_i_title = $mysqli->real_escape_string($mon_i_title);
$mon_i_by = $mysqli->real_escape_string($mon_i_by);

if ($mon_i_img != "") {

    $sql_i = "INSERT INTO monthspicture (mon_title, mon_by, mon_img) VALUES('$mon_i_title', '$mon_i_by', '$mon_i_img')";
        echo "<div class='success-box'>Your post have been created.</div>";

}else{

    $sql_i = "INSERT INTO monthspicture (mon_title, mon_by) VALUES('$mon_i_title', '$mon_i_by')";   
        echo "<div class='success-box'>Your post have been created. (Without image)</div>";
}

if (!$mysqli->query($sql_i)) {
 echo "Insert failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
 die();
}else{

}
?>
```

Tried adding: print_r($_POST); print_r($_FILES);

```
Array ( [mon_by] => AthaxDesigns [mon_title] => The Sunrise [mon_submit] => Opret [mon_id] => ) Array ( [mon_img] => Array ( [name] => Athax---The-sunrise.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => D:\wamp\tmp\phpF488.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 673646 ) )
```

Comment: add `print_r($_POST); print_r($_FILES);`

Comment: well it does submit, so what appears on the page?

Comment: Nothing appears, sadly, it just reloads the site. Without uploading the picture or add anything to the database.

Comment: (Aside: we _really_ like informative titles here, in common with most sources of tech assistance on the web. If everyone used `I'm encountering some kind of fault` then we might as well do away with titles completely. Please always try to describe the problem succinctly in 5-10 words, so that readers know briefly what they are clicking on. Thanks!)

Comment: After submitting, what happens if you press the refresh button? Does your browser ask you whether you are sure you wish to re-submit? If so, that means you are not getting as far as the `header()` redirect. If not, that means your redirect is working, but the upload is not being handled correctly.

Comment: serious question - did you write all that code then test it? i test almost every single line as i go along.

Comment: @halfer im sorry about being uninformative, i will do my best next time, and yes it does not ask me to resubmit.

Comment: No apology necessary, just letting you know how it works around here. OK, so if you don't get a resubmit message, it means it _did_ redirect, and it's worth checking to see what went wrong. `echo` and `exit` prior to the redirect are helpful here.

Comment: @halfer this might be eaiser for both of us, here's a screen share link: https://join.me/527-245-702 it works through the browser and you can even take controle of my screen.

Comment: The problem has been found I was a dummy, and did a typo in one of my $_POST['names']

Comment: @halfer how do i mark this post problem fixed?

Comment: Just submit your own answer, and click on the 'tick' mark to the left so it goes green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been found I was a dummy, and did a typo in one of my $_POST['names']; Thanks to everybody who tried to help me.